# Strange SQL 2008 R2 Sp3 Ent behavior - redistribute data across multiple files

Tags: sql-server-2008

I’ve got a 5TB database (Database_PROD) in one data file (1,5 TB of empty space in it). Installed some time ago by someone on SQL Server 2008 R2 SP3 Enterprise. Database contains 2726 tables and 5399 indexes. All data files are stored in on PRIMARY / Default file group. I’ve added 3 additional files to improve the performance (set each of them to 1/4 of the total database size with no auto-growth enabled). When I tried to empty the main file (3/4 of it's data) and redistribute the data into the 3 additional files after 7 hours almost no data has been redistributed and script is working without any significant progress (screen in the comments) I tried the process on the small 1 GB database and it works smooth without any issues.

Script which I run to empty the 3/4 of the main file into the 3 additional files is:

DBCC SHRINKFILE (Database_PROD, EMPTYFILE);

Could you give me some suggestion what the issue could be ? 
Maybe I should shrink the original data file to remove the empty space first ? Other option is to upgrade the SQL to the newer supported version e.g. SQL 2019.

Comment: What command did you run to "redistribute the data"?  Additional files won't necessarily improve performance unless they are on disks with isolated IOPS.

Comment: I'm using this script: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Premier-Field-Engineering/Split-a-file-group-into-multiple-data-files/ba-p/371344 . First I need 4 files, then verify if the performance improved, then think about distributing files across dedicated disks. Without step 1 there is no possible to implement next steps.

Comment: How many tables and indexes are in the file group?

Comment: 2726 tables, 5399 indexes. All data files are stored in on PRIMARY / Default filegroup. That has been installed many years ago by someone. Now I try to fix that situation up somehow.

Comment: Data status/size of the files (before and after emptying of the main file started) https://imgur.com/EMK2qZP

Comment: Data verification script: https://imgur.com/ARyQYFP

Comment: All files in PRIMARY/Default file group. SQL Server 2008 R2 SP3 Enterprise.